# nginx proxy_cache_key with a single $scheme

Tags: linux, caching, nginx

I have tested proxy_cache_key with a single $scheme

```
 proxy_cache_key $scheme;
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
```

Then I request one to cache.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/a.html
```

Then I requested again to confirm the cache

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/a.html
```

No problem

Then I request other url

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/b.html
```

And hope that it hits cache because the key is $scheme

but it gave me the content of b.html

Why      `proxy_cache_key $scheme;` does not work?

Comment: Did you define cache zone with `proxy_cache_path` and use it with `proxy_cache`?

Comment: The most probably means that caching is still no working. Do a `curl -v`, also check you cache folder and see if the cache is actually generated or not